# JAXB MOXy Binder issue when using @XmlAnyElement annotation

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I have an issue when using the Binder implementation in MOXy.
Here is the input XML document (input.xml)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <unmapped />
</root>
```

And now, here is the source code used to unmarshal XML into a Binder instance and then update the XML from the corresponding Java object:

```java
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Input.class);

DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new File("input.xml"));

Binder<Node> binder = context.createBinder(Node.class);
Input input = (Input) binder.unmarshal(document);

binder.updateXML(input);
```

In the end, the very simple Input class file:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
public class Input {
    @XmlAnyElement
    protected Object[] elements;
}
```

When the `updateXML()` method is invoked, the following exception is thrown:

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jaxb.DomHandlerConverter.convertObjectValueToDataValue(DomHandlerConverter.java:97)
```

Answer (score 0):

We have been able to confirm this issue and it looks like it will be a very quick fix.  You can use the link below to track our progress on this issue.

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/391237

---

**UPDATE**

A fix has been checked into the EclipseLink 2.5.0 stream, a nightly download can be obtained from the following location:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

We have also checked in a fix to the EclipseLink 2.4.2 stream.  A nightly download can be obtained from the above location starting October 12, 2012.

Comment: The fix is working fine (tested with 2.5.0 stream). Thanks a lot.